# How to fix: update of view in private qgis.db failed error

Tags: qgis, error, database

After a change in permissions, I started to get this error message:

> Update of view in private qgis.db failed.
>   table vw_srs already exists

I know that changing the ownership of the db or deleting it and letting QGIS create a new one could solve the problem, but in my case, this is not an option. An option would be not to update qgis.db. Does anybody know, how to "switch off" this checking and updating?

And why is this db checked every time I start QGIS anyway?

Answer (score 4):

I issued a bug and, in short, the response is:
Qgis needs write access to that db, so the only solution is to change the permissions.

Comment: If this file is inside `~/.qgis2/qgis.db`, why isn't QGIS creating the file with the correct permissions in the first place?